# How to fix the error generated while generating SPDK thread

Tags: linux, multithreading, huge-pages

Hello I am new with SPDK and have done all the steps mentioned in the https://spdk.io/doc/getting_started.html completely and without observing any errors.

But when I run the following simple code on my system

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <spdk/bdev.h>
#include <spdk/thread.h>
#include <spdk/queue.h>

void main()
{

    struct spdk_thread* first_reader_thread =
            spdk_thread_create("first_reader_thread", NULL);

    if (first_reader_thread == NULL)
    {
        printf("First thread creation failed...\n");
        return ;
    }

    struct spdk_thread* second_reader_thread =
            spdk_thread_create("second_reader_thread", NULL);
    if (second_reader_thread == NULL)
    {
        printf("Second thread creation failed...\n");
        return ;
    }

    printf("first reader thread id is: %"PRIu64"\n",
           spdk_thread_get_id(first_reader_thread));
    printf("second reader thread id is: %"PRIu64"\n",
           spdk_thread_get_id(second_reader_thread));
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return;
}
```

I get the following error:

"**RING: Cannot reserve memory for tailq, 
thread.c: 260:spdk_thread_create: *ERROR*: Unable to allocate memory for message ring, 
First thread creation failed...**"

it will be appraciated if anyone can guide me to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the SPDK environment before you use any API in the SPDK library.
Try to call `spdk_env_init` before other actions.